# Stream only partially read when downloading object from Amazon AWS S3

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to simply download an object from my bucket using C# just like we can find in S3 examples, and I can't figure out why the stream won't be entirely copied to my byte array. Only the first 8192 bytes are copied instead of the whole stream.

I have tried with with an `Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client` and with an `Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility`, but in both cases only the first bytes are actually copied into the buffer.

```
var stream = await _transferUtility.OpenStreamAsync(BucketName, key);
using (stream)
{
    byte[] content = new byte[stream.Length];
    stream.Read(content, 0, content.Length);
    // Here content should contain all the data from the stream, but only the first 8192 bytes are actually populated.
}
```

When debugging, I see the stream type is `Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.Md5Stream`, and inside the stream, before calling `Read()` the property `CurrentPosition` = 0. After the call, `CurrentPosition` becomes 8192, which seems to indeed indicate only the first 8K of data was read. The total `Length` of the stream is 104042.

If I make more calls to `stream.Read()`, I see more data gets read and `CurrentPosition` increases in value. But `CurrentPosition` is not a public property, and I cannot access it in my code to make a `while()` loop (and having to code such loops to read all the data seems a bit clunky).

Why are only the first 8K read in my code? How should I proceed to read the entire stream?

I tried calling `stream.Flush()`, but it did not fix the problem.

**EDIT 1**

I have modified my code so it does the following:

```
var stream = await _transferUtility.OpenStreamAsync(BucketName, key);
using (stream)
{
    byte[] content = new byte[stream.Length];
    var bytesRead = 0;

    while (bytesRead < stream.Length)
        bytesRead += stream.Read(content, bytesRead, content.Length - bytesRead);
}
```

And it works. But still looks clunky. Is it normal I have to do this?

**EDIT 2**

Final solution is to create a MemoryStream of the correct size and then call `CopyTo()`. So no clunky loop anymore and no risk of infinite loop if `Read()` starts returning 0 before the whole stream has been read:

```
var stream = await _transferUtility.OpenStreamAsync(BucketName, key);
using (stream)
{
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream((int)stream.Length))
    {
        stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        var myBuffer = memoryStream.GetBuffer();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't ignore the return value of `stream.Read`. The linked dupe will see you good.

Comment: Yes, it's normal to loop when using `stream.Read`. You could create a `MemoryStream` (possibly of the required size if you can get the content-length ahead of time) then simply `stream.CopyTo(myMemoryStream)`.

Comment: For each call you are overwriting the content buffer. You need to include the starting location in the buffer.

Comment: You also need to handle the case where the return bytes is 0 otherwise your code will loop forever on error.

Comment: @JohnHanley look carefully, the second param of `Read()` is `bytesRead`. So the correct offset is always used for each reads, no overwrite.

Comment: You are correct - where are my glasses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stream.Read()` returns the number of bytes read. You can then keep track of the total number of bytes read until you have reached the end of the file (`content.Length`).

You could also just loop until the returned value is 0 meaning `error` / `no more bytes left`.

You will need to keep track of the current offset for your content buffer so that you are not overwriting data for each call.